# Bulk image compression on server via php

Tags: php, image-processing

I am developing a content management kind of thing where user can upload their content with images and other stuff on php

Some user have uploaded image larger size may be a 1MB image for logo of page. 
I want to compress all the images present in the folder containing images of all users recursively.

So how that can be done using php or any server site scripting.

Note : I dont have a shell access to server to run any script. The only way to do it using something in php

Comment: use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php should get you started. GLOB to scan the dir. Filesize for your if statement wether to action on it or not.

Comment: I think you should at least make an attempt at writing some code and add that code in the question.